# android google maps - change GPS icon

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Im try to change the default blue dot and circle that Google Maps API V2 uses to set my position using GPS.

How can i change default google maps GPS dot and circle, to my own .ico? I am using:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

and i also have a LatLng variable with the current location.
Im using Google Maps API V2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please refer to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) under the changing Marker color title

Comment: this tutorial only show how to put a custom marker on my map, doesnt show how to replace the usual gps marker.